# pandas select value in a row and then the next 3 rows after it

Tags: python, pandas, select, indexing, row

I'm a Data Science beginner and have the following task.

I have a huge list of data and need to pick the rows starting with `scope_list` but also the next 4 following rows of the filtered data. I have the row `scope_list` 1 to x times in the list, see below. To select the first row is no problem for me, but not the next 3 rows.

```
df_new = df.loc[df['parts'] == 'Scope_list']
df_new
```

which get all ids and rows where the value in column `Parts` is `Scope_list`

```
         parts
0   Scope_list
10  Scope_list
18  Scope_list
```

but I need not only the first row "Scope_list" also the next 3 rows
like

```
          Parts
0    Scope_list
1   Light_front
2          Box1
3        Cable1
4    Scope_list
5   Light_front
6        Cable1
7     Connector
8    Scope_list
9    Light_left
10         Box2
11       Cable3
```

so thats a part of my df:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['Scope_list', 'Light_front', 'Box1', 'Cable1', 'Connector', 'Switch', 'Info_list', 'can be used for 1', '456 not used','','Scope_list', 'Light_front', 'Cable1', 'Connector', 'Code_list', '345,456,567', '567', '', 'Scope_list', 'Light_left', 'Box2', 'Cable3', 'Switch3'], columns = ['parts'])
```

May anybody can give me a hint and help would be great. I use jupyter notebook and python 3.

Answer (score 1):

First get the indexes where 'Scope_list' is the value and then get the next 3 values:

```
scope_idx = df.loc[df.parts == 'Scope_list'].index
out = df.loc[[e for lst in [range(idx, idx + 4) for idx in
             scope_idx] for e in lst]].copy()
out = out.reset_index(drop=True)
```

print(out):

```
          parts
0    Scope_list
1   Light_front
2          Box1
3        Cable1
4    Scope_list
5   Light_front
6        Cable1
7     Connector
8    Scope_list
9    Light_left
10         Box2
11       Cable3
```

Comment: thx a lot to all of you, great and fast help

Answer (score 0):

```
indexes = df[df['parts'].str.contains('Scope_list')].index
pd.concat([df.iloc[indexes[i]:indexes[i]+3] for i in range(len(indexes))])
```

I hope this will work fine. you can also bind this code in a function just pass the keyword you wanna search and the column name.

```
def func(column_name : string , keyword : string, show_items_after_keyword : int):
 indexes = df[df[column_name].str.contains(keyword)].index
 result = pd.concat([df.iloc[indexes[i]:indexes[i]+show_items_after_keyword] for i in range(len(indexes))])
 return result
```

Comment: selam Mohammed  
wow, this was fast, thank you very much, it is working perfectly. 
Only one question, if  i want show me all rows starting with '´Scope_list' till the next empty row in this column appears.  

i think this works like  

def func(column_name : string , keyword : string, show_items_after_keyword : int):
 indexes = df[df[parts].str.contains('')].index
 result = pd.concat([df.iloc[indexes[i]:indexes[i]+show_items_after_keyword] for i in range(len(indexes))])
 return result  

but it returns  

NameError: name 'string' is not defined

Comment: then change the code to this if you wanna stop your code after empty line

pd.concat([df.iloc[indexes[i]:indexes[i+1]] for i in range(len(indexes)-1) if df.iloc[indexes[i+1]][0] != ''])

Also thumbs up for the answer and upvote it, thanks.

Comment: thx a lot to all of you, great and fast help, problem solved

Comment: then kindly upvote and accept the answer, so others too make benefit from it...