# Python pandas. How to include rows before specific conditioned rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file, which for ex. kinda looks. like this:

| duration | concentration | measurement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.2 | 0 | 10 |
| 1.25 | 0 | 12 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 10.3 | 0 | 11 |
| 10.5 | 10 | 100 |
| 10.6 | 20 | 150 |
| 10.67 | 30 | 156 |
| 10.75 | 0 | 12.5 |
| 11 | 0 | 12 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I filtered all the rows with the concentration 0 with the following code.

```
dF2 = dF1[dF1["concentration"]>10][["duration","measurement","concentration"]]
```

But I would like to have 100(or n specific) extra rows, with the concentration hold on 0, before the rows with concentrations bigger than 10 begins, that I can have a baseline when plotting the data.

Does anybody had experience with a similar problem/ could somebody help me please...

Comment: Try to write your input in proper code format, it'll be easier for the community to help

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73936395/pandas-select-value-in-a-row-and-then-the-next-3-rows-after-it/73937395#73937395

Comment: Thank you all for feedback and help. Also sry for the late reply i m new with python/coding and the platform. Hope it'll get better:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean masks for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# number of baseline rows to keep
n = 2
# cols to keep
cols = ['duration', 'measurement', 'concentration']

# is the concentration greater than 10?
m1 = dF1['concentration'].gt(10)
# is the row one of the n initial concentration 0?
m2 = dF1['concentration'].eq(0).cumsum().le(n)

# if you have values in between 0 and 10 and do not want those
# m2 = (m2:=dF1['concentration'].eq(0)) & m2.cumsum().le(n)
# or
# m2 = df.index.isin(dF1[dF1['concentration'].eq(0)].head(n).index)

# keep rows where either condition is met
dF2 = dF1.loc[m1|m2, cols]
```

If you only want to keep initial rows before the first value above threshold, change `m2` to:

```
# keep up to n initial rows with concentration=0
# only until the first row above threshold is met
m2 = dF1['concentration'].eq(0).cumsum().le(n) & ~m1.cummax()
```

output:

```
   duration  measurement  concentration
0      1.20         10.0              0
1      1.25         12.0              0
4     10.60        150.0             20
5     10.67        156.0             30
```

Comment: @JChoi you're welcome, let me know which alternative works for you (there is room for interpretation)

Comment: @JChoi maybe open a new question with an explicit example?

Comment: Sure, it might be take some time, since  python/coding is smth new for me but i ll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the records and concat to have desired results

```
n = 100 # No of initial rows with concentratin 0 required

dF2 = pd.concat([dF1[dF1["concentration"]==0].head(n),dF1[dF1["concentration"]>10]])[["duration","measurement","concentration"]]
```

Comment: This may not identify the rows specifically *before* the rows with the concentration above 10, as the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter the data frame for when the concentration is zero, and select the top 100 or top n rows from your filtered data frame using the 'head' and append that to your dF2.

```
n = 100 # you can change this to include the number of rows you want.
    df_baseline = dF1[dF1["concentration"] == 0][["duration","measurement","concentration"]].head(n)
    
    dF2 = dF1[dF1["concentration"]>10][["duration","measurement","concentration"]]

    df_final = df_baseline.append(df2)
```

Comment: This may not identify the rows specifically *before* the rows with the concentration above 10, as the OP wants.